# Evaluating same column data.table in r

Tags: r, position, data.table, evaluate

How can I evaluate a column of a data.table with values of the same column, **each value against the value of the next two positions**. The following example ilustrates the problem and desired result.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = c(2, 3, 2, 4))   
result <- data.table(a = c(2, 3, 2, 4), b = c(T, F, NA, NA))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `shift` to create two `lead` columns based on 'a' by specifying `n= 1:2`.  Loop through the columns with `lapply`, check whether it is equal to 'a', `Reduce` it to a single logical vector with `|` and assign it to 'b' column

```
dt[, b := Reduce(`|`, lapply(shift(a, 1:2, type = 'lead'), `==`,  a))]
dt
#   a     b
#1: 2  TRUE
#2: 3 FALSE
#3: 2    NA
#4: 4    NA
```

As @Mike H. suggested if we are comparing only for the next values, then doing this individually may be better to understand

```
dt[, b := (shift(a, 1, type = 'lead') == a) | (shift(a, 2, type = 'lead') ==a)]
```

Comment: Not worth another answer or suggesting a change, just wanted to note that `dt$a == shift(dt$a, 1, type = "lead") | dt$a == shift(dt$a, 2, type = "lead")` does the same thing for anyone having trouble visualizing what your code does. Your code is much more flexible though (e.g. what if you wanted to do 5, or 10 lags?)

Answer (score 2):

You could do a rolling join on row number:

```
dt[, r := .I]
dt[head(1:.N, -2), found := 
  dt[.SD[, .(a = a, r = r + 1L)], on=.(a, r), roll=-1, .N, by=.EACHI]$N > 0L]

   a r found
1: 2 1  TRUE
2: 3 2 FALSE
3: 2 3    NA
4: 4 4    NA
```

To see how it works, replace `.N` with `x.r`:

```
dt[head(1:.N, -2), dt[.SD[, .(a = a, r = r + 1L)], on=.(a, r), roll=-1, x.r, by=.EACHI]]

   a r x.r
1: 2 2   3
2: 3 3  NA
```

The idea is that we look for the nearest `a` match starting from `r+1` and giving up after rolling one more ahead.